# How can I separate integers as dual parts in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have defined an array:

```
years = (2014..Time.now.year + 1).to_a
#=> [2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]
```

I want to show an output like this:

```
['2014-2015', '2015-2016', '2016-2017', '2017-2018']
```

Do you have any good advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to reinvent the wheel, just use `map`:

```
(2014..Time.now.year).map { |year| "#{year}-#{year + 1}" } 
#=> ["2014-2015", "2015-2016", "2016-2017", "2017-2018"]
```

Answer (score 3):

[Enumerable#each_cons](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons)

> Iterates the given block for each array of consecutive  elements.

```
(2014..Time.now.year + 1).each_cons(2).to_a # => [[2014, 2015], [2015, 2016], [2016, 2017], [2017, 2018]]
```

I believe you can handle the rest.

Comment: why so complex? `Range->Enumerator->Array->...`?

Comment: @Ilya: Good point. In this particular example there is, indeed, a simpler way, as evidenced by your answer. Still, `each_cons` is worth learning about. Super-useful at times. :)

Comment: IMO, `each_cons` communicates the intent more clearly, and I don't find `years.each_cons(2).map { |pair| pair.join('-') }` to be complex at all.